# How to set hive.metastore.warehouse.dir in HiveContext?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-hive

I'm trying to write a unit test case that relies on `DataFrame.saveAsTable()` (since it is backed by a file system). I point the hive warehouse parameter to a local disk location:

```
sql.sql(s"SET hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=file:///home/myusername/hive/warehouse")
```

By default, Embedded Mode of metastore should be enabled, thus doesn't require an external database.

But HiveContext seems to be ignoring this configuration: since I still get this error when calling saveAsTable():

```
MetaException(message:file:/user/hive/warehouse/users is not a directory or unable to create one)
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:file:/user/hive/warehouse/users is not a directory or unable to create one)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:619)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog.createDataSourceTable(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.CreateMetastoreDataSourceAsSelect.run(commands.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.execute(commands.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:1099)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:1099)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.saveAsTable(DataFrame.scala:1121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.saveAsTable(DataFrame.scala:1071)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.saveAsTable(DataFrame.scala:1037)
```

This is quite annoying, why is it still happening and how to fix it?

Comment: `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL` doesn't help as well.
Seems that it is too late when context have been already instantiated.

Comment: wondering if you've ever solved this issue - I'm having same problem

Comment: same problem here (spark 1.6.1). tried setting with hive-site.xml and it seems to ignore it (but do parse the file as it fails launching if there is a xml syntax error)

Answer (score 4):

According to http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#sql

> Note that the hive.metastore.warehouse.dir property in hive-site.xml
>   is deprecated since Spark 2.0.0. Instead, use spark.sql.warehouse.dir
>   to specify the default location of database in warehouse.

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr** Set `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` while creating a `SQLContext` (or `SparkSession`).

The location of the default database for the Hive metastore warehouse is `/user/hive/warehouse` by default. It used to be set using `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` Hive-specific configuration property (in a Hadoop configuration).

It's been a while since you asked this question (it's Spark 2.3 days), but that part has not changed since - if you use `sql` method of `SQLContext` (or `SparkSession` these days), it's simply too late to change where Spark creates the metastore database. It is *far* too late as the underlying infrastructure has been set up already (so you can use the `SQLContext`). The warehouse location has to be set up before the `HiveContext` / `SQLContext` / `SparkSession` initialization.

You should set `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` while creating `SparkSession` (or `SQLContext` before Spark SQL 2.0) using [config](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$Builder@config(key:String,value:String):org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.Builder) and (very important) enable the Hive support using [enableHiveSupport](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$Builder@enableHiveSupport():org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.Builder).

> **config(key: String, value: String): Builder** Sets a config option. Options set using this method are automatically propagated to both SparkConf and SparkSession's own configuration.
>
> **enableHiveSupport(): Builder** Enables Hive support, including connectivity to a persistent Hive metastore, support for Hive serdes, and Hive user-defined functions.

You could use `hive-site.xml` configuration file or `spark.hadoop` prefix, but *I'm digressing* (and it strongly depends on the current configuration).

Comment: i have set the `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` to a remove hive database `hdfs://xx.xx.xx:8020/user/hive/warehouse` and then i enabled enableHiveSupport() even though its unable to read the tables from the hive do i have to change the XML file adding some properties to them as well ?

Comment: What's the Spark version? How did you set the configuration?

Comment: Iam using spark 2.3.2 setting the configuration like below

`val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("ApplicationName")
      .master("yarn")
      .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
      .config("spark.executor.memory", "48120M")
      .config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://ip-10-129-224-21.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hive/warehouse")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()`

Comment: Can you set the option on command line when you `spark-submit`?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to just create a new database and then USE new_DATATBASE and then create the table. The warehouse will be created under the folder you ran the sql-spark.

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly theI faced exactly the same issues. I was running spark-submit command in shell action via oozie.

Setting warehouse directory doesn't worked for me while creating sparksession

All you need to do is to pass the pass the hive-site.xml  in spark-submit command using below property:

--files ${location_of_hive-site.xml}